# TypeORM handle database outage

Tags: sql-server, typescript, typeorm

Let's say my MSSQL server has crashed and my app client requests something from the API. Right now it will just spin until the unanswered request is timed out by Express.

When logging is enabled in TypeORM I can see that the relevant query is executed.

I would prefer to return an API response informing the client that the database is unreachable.

This is the actual code in my user controller

```js
public static listAll = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const userRepository = getRepository(User);
    const users = await userRepository
        .find()
    res.send(users);
};
```

I have tried to .catch the request that is being used in the relevant controller, but doesn't seem to change anything. See example below.

```
const users = await userRepository
    .find()
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error); // this is never triggered
});
```

No error message is logged out in console.

These are my connection options in TypeORM

```js
createConnection({
    type: 'mssql',
    host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.TYPEORM_PORT, 0),
    username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true,
    entities: models,
    cli: {
        entitiesDir: 'src/entity',
        migrationsDir: 'src/migration',
        subscribersDir: 'src/subscriber',
    },
})
    .then(connection => {
        const server = http.createServer(App);
        server.listen({ port: `${process.env.APP_PORT}` }, () => {
            console.log(` Server ready at http://${process.env.TYPEORM_HOST}:${process.env.APP_PORT}`);
        });

        if (connection.isConnected) {
            console.log(`Database ${connection.options.database} connected`);
        }
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

I also tried to set requestTimeout in createConnection to 1000 (ms), with same result.

Comment: Adding `catch` made things *worse* by hiding errors. It won't do anything if `find()` never throws

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I appreciate your comment, but why does find() not throw any error when the database is unavailable?

Comment: @fantastik Right now, your code awaits the promise generated by `catch`, not `find`. Have you tried using `try/catch, ie ` try `{  const users = await userRepository.find(); res.send(users);} catch (error){...}`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This causes exactly the same problem 
```try {
   const userRepository = getRepository(User);
   const users = await userRepository.find();
   res.send(users);
  } catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
  }```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class App {

  public app:     express.Application;
  public db:      Connection;


  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.appConfiguration();
  }

  public async appConfiguration() {

    try {
      this.db = await Database.init();

      // Make use of JSON Body
      this.app.use(bodyParser.json());

      // Inits Routes
      Routes.init(this.app);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('database is not reachable, see error:', err)
    };

  }

  public getApp(): express.Application {
    return this.app;
  }

}
```

Database.init() is used for creating a connection to the db:

```
export class Database {

  public static init() {

    return createConnection({
      type: "postgres",
      host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
      port: parseInt(process.env.TYPEORM_PORT),
      database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
      username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
      entities: [
        User
      ],
      synchronize: process.env.TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE == "true" ? true : false,
      logging: process.env.TYPEORM_LOGGING == "true" ? true : false
    });

  }

}
```

Result when changing db name to some random DB I'll get error messages in the console:

```
    [nodemon] starting `ts-node src/server.ts`
Server listening on port 5000
database is not reachable, see error:
{ error: database "express_text_typeorms" does not exist
    at Connection.parseE 
    at Connection.parseMessage 
    at Socket.<anonymous> 
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  name: 'error',
  length: 106,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '3D000',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'postinit.c',
  line: '890',
  routine: 'InitPostgres' }
```

Is that what you're trying to acchieve?

Comment: Yes and no. Getting an error message when database is offline is part of my question, but the main issue is sending a response to the client about database outage if that is the case. However I was not able to replicate the database is not reachable by wrapping my createConnection in a try...catch statement, which is the second part of my problem.

Comment: So you are basically asking if / how it's possible to send an error message to the client whenever the DB outages while the server is running?

Comment: Maybe you could create your own custom logger, which could send out a message to your client upon specific events (https://typeorm.io/#/logging/changing-default-logger). But I guess this would again only work as a response to a request. 

Another thing could be a small services that pings your DB every 1 to 1,5 seconds and sends out a message to the client if necessary.

Comment: Sounds a bit overkill. This is the basic flow I'm looking for: Client requests resource from API -> API tries to query from database, but database is unavailable -> API responds with "Ooops. Database is unavailable at the moment."

Comment: You could try something like this:

`const users = () => { 
  try {
    --- Query here + return result ---
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}`

Comment: The problem is that TypeORM is not throwing any error when DB is inaccessible at all. Only when starting the app.